# Tick check box and enables submit button not working in IE6/7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is working fine in firefox but ie just doesn't want to know:

```
$("#termsandconditionscontinue").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $("#agreeTandC").click(function() {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            if (checked_status == true) {
                $("#termsandconditionscontinue").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("#termsandconditionscontinue").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/LXGMu/

Comment: I've tested your fiddle in IE7 and 8 and it's working. What behaviour are you getting?

Comment: try `$(this).is(':checked')` or `$(this).attr('checked')`

Comment: @ipr101: It may not be working in IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can lie in

```
var checked_status = this.checked;
```

Change it to:

```
var checked_status = $(this).attr("checked");
```

to make sure you use proper jQuery object which is cross browser compatible.

Comment: Hi I have found a better solution I have used the .prop .prop('disabled', true);